# How to disable hibernate sql logs in log4j2 with spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, log4j2, hibernate-search-6

We have an application written in spring boot. We are using Hibernate search 6 to fetch data from elasticsearch.
We have configured log4j2 as below:

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" packages="net.xxxx.logging">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        </Console>
        <Console name="ConsoleDev" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t]
      %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
      </Appenders>
      <Loggers>
          <Logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="${env:LOG_LEVEL_HIKARI:-INFO}" additivity="false" >
              <AppenderRef ref="${env:LOG_CONSOLE:-Console}" />
          </Logger>
          <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO" additivity="false" >
              <AppenderRef ref="${env:LOG_CONSOLE:-Console}" />
          </Logger>
          <Logger name="org.hibernate.search.fulltext_query" level="INFO" additivity="false" >
              <AppenderRef ref="${env:LOG_CONSOLE:-Console}" />
          </Logger>
          <Logger name="org.springframework" level="${env:LOG_LEVEL_SPRING:-INFO}" additivity="false" >
              <AppenderRef ref="${env:LOG_CONSOLE:-Console}" />
          </Logger>
          <Logger name="org.springframework.ldap" level="${env:LOG_LEVEL_LDAP:-INFO}" additivity="false" >
              <AppenderRef ref="${env:LOG_CONSOLE:-Console}" />
          </Logger>
          <Root level="INFO" includeLocation="false">
              <AppenderRef ref="${env:LOG_CONSOLE:-Console}" />
          </Root>
      </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**application.yaml:**

```
spring:
  profiles: development
  liquibase.enabled: false
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: false
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        generate_statistics: false
        search:
          enabled: true
          backend:
            type: elasticsearch
            dynamic_mapping: true
            uris: ${ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}
            aws:
              region: us-west-2
              signing.enabled: true
```

We want to show hibernet sql queries logs show in debug mode only(in local environment) not in production build environment.

We tried by setting `show_sql= false` in application.yaml file but it disable logs on local and prod both environment. We want to enable to log sql queries in local environment.

Comment: use `spring.config.activate.on-profile` instead of `spring.profiles`

Comment: I'm not sure why you mentioned Hibernate Search, since it's not really related to your questions, but just in case you're also after Elasticsearch request logs, here's how to enable them: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#troubleshooting-logging-elasticsearch-request

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Profiles` from spring boot [spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles). The best way to get what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Profile for segregation between your Local and Production environment. Create two different copies of application.yml file like - application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml. Here in application-dev.yml you can enable the hibernate logs with `show_sql= true` while in another file application-prod.yml you can disable it `show_sql= false`.

You will have to create an environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` for picking files depending on your instance. Suppose your instance is development then you need to set this variable to `dev` otherwise it would be `prod`.

To switch profiles you can use one of the following options:

JVM property  : `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`
Command line switch: `--spring.profiles.active=dev`
Property file : `spring.profiles.active=dev`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a spring profile like this:

In your **application.yml** you configure the active profile depending on which branches you are in. If you are in dev it will take the properties of application-dev and if you are in prod of application-prod

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod #dev #staging
```

**application-dev**

```
liquibase.enabled: false
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: false
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        generate_statistics: false
        search:
          enabled: true
          backend:
            type: elasticsearch
            dynamic_mapping: true
            uris: ${ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}
            aws:
              region: us-west-2
              signing.enabled: true
```

**application-prod**

```
liquibase.enabled: false
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: false
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        generate_statistics: false
        search:
          enabled: true
          backend:
            type: elasticsearch
            dynamic_mapping: true
            uris: ${ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}
            aws:
              region: us-west-2
              signing.enabled: true
```

You can even optimize more using enviroment variables in your properties.

```
jpa:
    show-sql: ${SHOW_SQL}
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: ${FORMAT_SQL}
```